# Widening margins in multi-panel figure to fit cross-panel titles using grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I need to widen margins in a grid.arrange object. Here is an example to illustrate the problem

```
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
```

Here are some figures

```
g1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
g2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
g3 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
g4 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Petal.Length)) + geom_point()
```

Now let's say I want to put all these into a multi-panel figure using the amazing `grid.arrange()` function from the `gridExtra` and `grid` packages. And let's also say I want to add some cross-panel titles as well, titles that span several of my figures.

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, g4, ncol = 2, nrow = 2,
                        left = textGrob("Cross-panel title 1",
                                        gp = gpar(fontsize = 16),
                                        rot = 90),
                        right = textGrob("Cross-panel title 1",
                                        gp = gpar(fontsize = 16),
                                        rot = 270,
                                        vjust = 0)) -> panelG
```

Note that I want to move the right-hand side y-axis title further away from the right hand side yaxes of the panels. So to do this is use the `vjust =`  argument within the `textGrob()` function. Now when I save the figure.

```
ggsave("panelG.jpg",
       plot = panelG,
       device = "jpg",
       width = 10,
       height = 10,
       units = c("cm"),
       limitsize = T)
```

[image]

It cuts off some of the text.

**How do I move the right y-axis cross-panel title further away from the axis without cutting off the text?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some more padding on the right side (up from default .5 to 1):

```r
gridExtra::grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, g4, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, padding=unit(c(.5,1),"line"),
                        left = textGrob("Cross-panel title 1",
                                        gp = gpar(fontsize = 16),
                                        rot = 90),
                        right = textGrob("Cross-panel title 2",
                                        gp = gpar(fontsize = 16),
                                        rot = 270,
                                        vjust = 0)) -> panelG
```

[image: added padding]

Comment: Padding, brilliant?! These are the solutions I love, when there is actually a dedicated argument for doing the thing I need. Thank you!

Comment: Just out of interest how does the `unit(c(.5,1),"line")` argument work?

Comment: It creates a 2-element vector , first is 05lines the second is 1lines (for left and right padding, try changing the values and see what happens!). The [manual](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grid/versions/3.6.2/topics/unit) explains more what these do or can do. In this exampleits just a way define the padding in units of "lines".